# Grafana with Prometheus Node Export

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I set up Prometheus + Node Exporter + Grafana with the following instructions: [klick](https://tech.david-cheong.com/monitoring-server-with-prometheus-grafana/)

[Node Exporter Config Prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRSye.png)

So, everything worked quite well. In Prometheus "Targets" and "Metrics" are working fine.

[Prometheus Targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QElk.png)
[Prometheus Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWrcY.png)

Then I went over to Grafana and but the "host" list is empty and there's no data.

[Grafana Dashboard Node Exporter Full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tEHi.png)

Then I taked a look into Grafana Dashboard "Prometheus Stats 2.0" and there is data from all three nodes.

[Grafana Dashboard Prometheus Stats 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZE4q.png)

So, I'm got stuck and I don't know how to figure out the problem. Perhaps anyone of the awesome guys here have an hint for me to help me out of this problems.

Thanks a lot for reading all of this in advance. Big hugs!

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) Node Exporter? The [Node Exporter Full dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860) uses some metrics to determine the "Job" and "Host" variables (see in "Dashboard settings" > "Variables" > "Query" field) which are not available in, for example, [Windows exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter). In your case, clearly, these variables were not determined correctly. Take a look at the definition of the variables and try to replace the metric with another suitable one.